# How to implement jQuery Accordion for a Menu?

Tags: theming, routes, javascript, navigation

I'm looking to implement something like the [Accordion Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/accordion_menu) module, but unfortunately that module has issues with Menu Block and other modules... so what's the best way to implement the jQuery Accordion menu with primary and secondary links, from a theming perspective? Should be a simple question for a themer, but I haven't found any specific tutorials that can take me step by step.

Using Drupal 7, Adaptive Theme.

update: thanks for all the responses. I'll look at all of the suggestions and provide another update :-)

---

**Madam Adam's solution: not working correctly yet**

> Only got it to work with this modification; added to js file

```
(function ($) {
//add drupal 7 code
Drupal.behaviors.myfunction = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
//end drupal calls

//some jquery goodness here...
$( "#accordion" ).accordion( {
  header: "li",
  collapsible: true
} );

}}})
(jQuery);
```

Comment: Whats the issue you are facing with accordion?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the accordion library by adding this line to your theme's template.php:

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
```

Then you trigger the accordion by adding this to yout template.php or an external js-file:

```
$( "#menu-container" ).accordion( {
  header: "li",
  collapsible: true
} );
```

Comment: ok so I finally got some type of accordion from jQuery using the following code:

Comment: added code and more info in post. Right now there is only one header and all other parent links are within the first parent link. Lets say I have 3 sibling links 1, 2, 3. Links 2 and 3 get nested within Link 1.  Maybe something wrong with my ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple jQuery script to create accordion like menus

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('li.expanded').mouseover(function(){

     jQuery(this).find('ul').show(200); 
    });
     jQuery('li.expanded').mouseout(function(){

     jQuery(this).find('ul').hide(); 
    })

    })
    </script>
<style>


 #nav > li{position:relative}
   #nav  li  ul.sf-menu{
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    width:150px
    }
    </style>
```

[image]
with little adjustment in css. Check classes in the image and how it is used in jQuery

Comment: wasn't able to get this to work at all.

Comment: I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

I found [flexnav](http://jasonweaver.name/lab/flexiblenavigation/) to be extremely useful.  There is a [module in development](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexnav) that makes most of the installation very easy,  can't recommend it enough.